# Vary the height of the splitter dynamically

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have implemented kendoUI splitter in my application. I want to vary the height of the splitter dynamically. I defined the splitter like this:

```
<div id="splitter" style="height:500px;width:100%">
  <div id="leftPane"></div>
  <div id="rightPane"></div>
</div>
$("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
  panes: [
    { collapsible: true, size: "50%" },
    { collapsible: true, size: "50%" }
  ],
  orientation: "horizontal",
});
```

I don't want to display the scrollbar in the panes. I want to increase the height of the splitter, in order to remove the scrollbar. Can you tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to resize the splitter you can do:

```
// Get reference to the splitter
var splitter = $("#splitter").data("kendoSplitter");
// Set the new height to 600px
splitter.wrapper.height(600);
```

But since there is no `redraw` method in `splitter` you should `trigger` a `resize` event by doing:

```
// Trigger a resize event in splitter to force a redraw.
splitter.trigger("resize");
```